# Updating multiple tables using single trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I am having trouble with updating 2 tables with one trigger, its giving me an error near "New.userid"

```
CREATE TRIGGER userDownloads AFTER INSERT ON Downloads
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE Project SET PROJECT_DOWNLOADS = PROJECT_DOWNLOADS + 1 WHERE PROJECTID = NEW.ProjectID,
UPDATE User SET NO_OF_DOWNLOADS = NO_OF_DOWNLOADS + 1 WHERE USERID = NEW.UserID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write your trigger this way:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER userDownloads AFTER INSERT ON Downloads
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE Project SET PROJECT_DOWNLOADS = PROJECT_DOWNLOADS + 1 WHERE PROJECTID = NEW.ProjectID;
  UPDATE User SET NO_OF_DOWNLOADS = NO_OF_DOWNLOADS + 1 WHERE USERID = NEW.UserID;
END//
```

Please see it working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5f30/1).

But are you sure you need a trigger? Why don't you just do a COUNT on your Downloads table?

```
SELECT ProjectID, COUNT(*) AS PROJECT_DOWNLOADS
FROM Downloads
GROUP BY ProjectID;

SELECT UserID, COUNT(*) AS NO_OF_DOWNLOADS
FROM Downloads
GROUP BY UserID;
```

Comment: i tried what you said before and i got the following error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 "

Comment: @fana please see my uptated answer, i changed `SEPARATOR` to `DELIMITER` which is the correct statement here. It will work if you are creating the TRIGGER at the console, but if you are using PHPMyAdmin or other tools there might be a different way to specify a delimiter